# Kernel Panic at boot please help

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

Can you please guide me through the necessary steps. After false installation of flgrx for graphic I got this error at boot screen 
        "`target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init`"
followed by kernel panic --not syncing.

I used boot-repair but was not able to boot. Problem perisist. Can you please look at my boot info http://paste.ubuntu.com/13742940/. 
When i choose an option "purge kernels and then re-install last kernel" Boot-repair stuck. I have tried every possible solution but no luck :(.

I am using ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Can you login to grub> on boot screen? Ctl Alt F1

Comment: i can go to grub command line by pressing letter 'c'

Comment: Click on System > Administration > Update Manager > Click on Check button > Apply all updates including kernel. (If you are on 32bit i would use sudo and can provide steps.)

Comment: i cannot boot in to have that option. I have grub console with list of possible commands. I have no idea what went wrong.

Comment: I would edit or make a new question for this/ if you have a live cd ypu can boot into rescue mode.

Comment: yes i can boot from live USB. I tried removing `flgrx` package which i remember was  last install by mounting necessary drives(  [with this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2036730) )  I tried boot-repair to restore grub but no luck. I tried to restore previous kernel  from boot-repair, the process do not get complete. I dont want to re-install entire OS for that simple changes :(

Comment: This is not a simple change; please read here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel

Comment: Thank you @DnrDevil  **I finally gave up and installing new version of ubuntu**

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to upgrade your Kernel[. Please Read Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel) You can update the kernel with the update manager safely.

*Click on System > Administration > Update Manager > Click on Check button > Apply all updates including kernel.

If you wish to proceed with upgrades outside these steps I would recommend making a backup of your system [Here](http://Clonezilla.com)

Run the following Terminal commands to install a new 32-bit Ubuntu kernel from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install python-bs4

cd /tmp

rm -rf medigeek-kmp*

wget --no-check-certificate https://github.com/medigeek/kmp-downloader/tarball/master -O kmpd.tar.gz

tar xzf kmpd.tar.gz

cd medigeek-*

python kmpd.py -d
```

You can roll back by selecting the previous (old) kernel at the boot menu and then un-install the (new) not working kernel.

With [Synaptic](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Synaptic) you can un-install previously installed kernel packages.

For More information visit [Kernel/Upgrade](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Upgrade) or [Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel)